# FQL query by server side

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, server-side

I do not understand how I can do: I have to do some queries on facebook by my server: I created a token with app_facebook_id and SECRET_KEY, my server starts to make these queries using FQL but I get an error: I do not have an active session! So how can I do this? I can use some information of the app facebook? these FQL queries are not linked to users' personal information ready but, probabily, facebook needs an active session by a logged user (the caller) ... in my case the caller is my server

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the bottom of each FQL table's [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/album) you'll find a section that describes required permissions.
If it requires particular user permissions or access token, you need to implement [user login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/) to get users' permissions and access tokens. If it only requires "any valid access_token" or "app access_token," then you can access with that app access token that you talked about.
Then use the access_token to retrieve data. It should be something like below.

```
curl -X GET \
'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT.......&access_token=XXXXX'
```

You can find and learn the basic implementation on [this guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/).

Comment: I want to know all public events by a user_id .. where can I find token_info about this query?

Comment: You might want to check the bottom of event_member table's document(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event_member) to see what permissions you need to get all public events a particular user is attending.
Or you can check https://graph.facebook.com/me/events (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) to get what events a user is attending. It is not FQL, but Graph API.